# nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Com.test.model.Client, at table: ComptePaiement

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

I'm using Hibernate in my spring project. But It doesn't work for One-To-One relationships. It gives me the below error.

```
Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: com.example.TransfertNational.model.Client, at table: ComptePaiement, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(client)]
```

I have ran some searches in the internet, but it doesn't work for me.

the Client Entity :

```
@Data @Entity
@AllArgsConstructor @NoArgsConstructor @ToString
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String typeTransfert;
    private String typePiece;
    private String cin;

    private String sexe;
    private String prenom;
    private String typePieceIdentite;
    private String paysEmission;
    private String numPI;
    private String validitePI;
    private String dateNaissance;
    private String profession;
    private String nationalite;
    private String paysAdresse;
    private String adresseLegale;
    private String ville;
    private String gsm;
    private String email;
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private Set<Beneficiaire> beneficiares;
    @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY,
            cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private ComptePaiement comptePaiement;
}
```

the ComptePaiement Entity :

```
@Data
@Entity
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class ComptePaiement {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String solde;
    private String rip;
    private Client client;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried setting property `mappedBy` on `@OneToOne` in `Client`?
I think that you also need `@OneToOne` and `JoinColumn` on `Client` attribute in `ComptePaiement`.

Comment: i added @JoinColumn(name = "comptePaiement_id", referencedColumnName = "id") to the Client Entity and deleted Client variable from ComptePaiement Entity and it work fine, thank you

Comment: Ok, I will make it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from comments:

You are probably missing `@JoinColumn` on `Client` or `ComptePaiement` and `mappedBy` in `@OneToOne` annotation, depending which will hold reference id in database.